# Tian's approach for solving the conjecture of invariance of plurigenera in Kahler setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-ricci-flow

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth holomorphic fibre space whose fibres $f^{-1}(y)$ have pseudoeffective canonical bundles. suppose that

$$\frac{\partial \omega(t)}{\partial t}=-Ric_{X/Y}(\omega(t))-\omega(t)$$ be a Kahler ricci flow that starts with semi-positive Kahler form $\omega_0$ (take it Weil-Petersson metric)

> Then the solution of $\omega(t)$ are semi-positive?
>
> In fact solution of this question leds to invariance of plurigenera in
>   Kahler setting. But I can not see how?

**Some information**: let $k$ large enough so that $kK_F$ has a nonzero global section for some fibre $F$. For any fibre $F$, we have $K_F = K_{X/Y}~_{|F}$. So deformation invariance of plurigenera says that the function

$$h^0(X_p, k K_{X/Y}~_{|X_p})$$
is constant on $Y$ (where now $X_p$ denotes the fibre over the point $p \in Y$).