# A question about invariance of plurigenera

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Choose $m$ large enough so that $mK_F$ has a non-zero global section for some fibre $F$. For any fibre $F$, we have $K_F = K_{X/D}~_{|F}$. So deformation invariance of plurigenera says that the function

$$\dim H^0(X_p, m K_{X/D}~_{|X_p})$$
is constant on $D$ (where now $X_p$ denotes the fibre over the point $p \in D$).  Or by analytical point of view, every section of $\sigma\in H^0(X_t,K_{K_t})$ can be extended to a section $\bar\sigma\in H^0(X,K_{K})$

> Let $\pi:X\to D$ (where $D$ is a disc) be a family of Kahler varieties
>   such that psudoeffectiveness of $K_{X_0}$ gives the psudoeffectiveness
>   of $K_{X_t}$  then can we say invariance of plurigenera holds true?

Comment: The invariance of plurigenera in the Kähler setting is still nowadays an open problem. Even in this (slightly) more particular case you mention.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "such that psudoeffectiveness of $K_{X_0}$ gives the psudoeffectiveness of $K_{X_t}$"?

Comment: If $X_0$ be centeral fiber such that the assumption of pseudoeffectivness of  $K_{X_0}$ led to all fibers have pseudoeffective canonical bundle . I think in smooth projective case it just work .

Comment: What kind of assumption is it? You assume that your central fiber has the property that its canonical bundle spreads out pseudoeffectiveness around? I still don't understand. It doesn't seem to me that pseudoeffectiveness is an open property in family (but maybe I am wrong). You might say that it could be at least for the canonical class. But it seems to me as well that even in the projective case where the invariance of plurigenera is known, this would use the non vanishing conjecture (which is, indeed, a conjecture).

Comment: Theorem 1.2 https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1114631736 but in Kahler case such theorem gives invariance of plurigenera?

Comment: here is the behind of my mind http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232875/the-conjecture-of-invariance-of-plurigenera-in-kahler-setting. We can solve invariance of plurigenera via Ricci flow theory, i.e. Analytical surgery. This is new approach of Tian

Comment: Ok, I was't aware of that paper by Tsuji. Anyway, as you can of course see by yourself, it doesn't say nothing about the Kähler case.

Comment: in fact the question is the statement "$K_{X_0}$ pseudoeffective =====>$K_{X_t}$ pseudoeffective " gives invariance of plurigenera in Kahler setting

Comment: In Ricci flow setting if you find a metric such that its curvature is semi positive and take it as initial metric then the solutions are semi-positive (conjecturally )and this gives a solution for invariance of plurigenera and also semi-positivity of Semi-Kahler Einstein metric (fiberwise Kahler Einstein metric )in singular setting is equivalent to invariance of plurigenera ;). For smooth case it solved by Georg Scumacher entitling Positivity of relative canonical bundles and applications

Comment: That paper of Tsuji that you link is widely believed to be (very) incomplete. See for example the discussion by Siu here http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/siu_reprints/siu_grauert_volume_paper.pdf on pages 264-276