# Kähler manifold which is not algebraic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, examples

Can someone provide examples of Kähler manifolds which are not algebraic?

This question came to my mind seeing [the post of Andrea Ferretti](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13400/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

generic complex tori in complex dimension 2 or higher.
   MR

Comment: You mean those which are not Abelian Varieties? Thanks! 

Comment: yes that is what I meant.MR

Comment: ramachndran ==> ramachandran?

Answer (score 4):

In (complex) dimension greater or equal with 2 there are complex tori which are not algebraic. A criterion for projectivity is that of Riemann (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_variety#Riemann_conditions).
  Also there are K3 surfaces which are not algebraic.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't in itself give specific examples, but the theoretical answer to the question "When is a compact Kahler manifold algebraic?" is given by the [Kodaira embedding theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodaira_embedding_theorem).  A nice exposition is given in Richard Wells' *Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*. Indeed, the KET is the crescendo to which the entire book builds.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. As it must have been obvious from the question, I knew dear nothing about Kahler manifold beyond their definition, and an awareness of their importance. 

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at this previous MO [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4895/the-relationship-between-complex-and-algebraic-geomety).

There, I mentioned [Voisin's](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410040) [results](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312032) disproving Kodaira's conjecture (every Kahler manifold 
is deformation equivalent to a projective manifold).